# Why is my CUDA kernel returning old values?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Kind of almost at the point of ripping my hair out over this issue.

I have a CUDA kernel that does some math on data stored in a 3D array. While testing this, I used to assign some values (non-zero) to the array and observe results. I **commented out** those lines since, but the result is still the same. It is as if it is completely  ignoring the fact that I'm doing a memset to 0.

The code works correctly when I step through it in Debug... But not in Release! **My guess is I have a memory leak from this matrix.**

I allocate this array as:

```
cudaExtent m_extent = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(float)*matdim.x, matdim.y, matdim.z); // width, height, depth
cudaPitchedPtr m_device;
cudaMalloc3D(&m_device, m_extent);
cudaMemset3D(m_device, 0, m_extent);
```

I call the kernel in a loop like this:

```
for (int iter = 0; iter < gpu_iterations; iter++)
    {
        PF_iteration_kernel<<<grids,threads>>>(m_device, m_extent, matdim);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); 
    }
```

After which I release the `m_device` pitched pointer:

```
cudaFree(m_device.ptr);
```

`matdim` is just matrix dimensions held by a dim3.

Within the kernel I do the following (well, I commented everything functional out...):

```
__global__ void PF_iteration_kernel(cudaPitchedPtr mPtr, cudaExtent mExt, dim3 matrix_dimensions)
{
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

// Find location within the pitched memory
char *m = (char*)mPtr.ptr;

int sof = sizeof(float);
size_t pitch = mPtr.pitch;
size_t slice_pitch = pitch*mExt.height;
char* m_addroff = m + y * pitch + x * sof;
printf("m(%d,%d) is %f \n", x, y, *m_addroff); // display the slice

*m_addroff = 0; // WILL THIS RESET IT?!

__syncthreads();
}
```

That should be just showing 0s, but it displays my old values (25, 26, 27, 28, etc).

I have cleaned and re-cleaned and re-built everything several times. I have relaunched the IDE.

My IDE is Visual Studio 2010 With NSight 4.6 (CUDA 7.0).
I am on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Has this previous SO question any relevance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611451/how-to-use-make-cudaextent-to-define-a-cudaextent-correctly

Comment: @WeatherVane, I don't think so. The accepted answer doesn't even release any memory that they allocated. All I'm doing is a Malloc and a Memset, but the person in the other question was asking about Memcpy as well.

Comment: In `printf("m(%d,%d) is %f \n", x, y, *m_addroff);` the compiler will surely see a `char` and promote it to `int` pushed on to stack - not a `float` promoted to `double` that the format requires? Because `char* m_addroff` is not a `float` and the compiler does not push args according to the format spec - although some compilers will warn of problems.

Comment: Interesting! I guess I gotta typecast `m_addroff` to float before attempting to printf() it. It must use some old values otherwise? I find it strange that it found some previous values to display anyways. But hey, if it works, it works. Thanks @WeatherVane :) If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it. (Wowzers...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this

```
char* m_addroff = m + y * pitch + x * sof;
printf("m(%d,%d) is %f \n", x, y, *m_addroff);
```

The compiler will see a `char` and promote it to `int` pushed on to stack - not a `float` promoted to `double` that the format requires.

The compiler does not provide arguments to fit the format spec, but some compilers will examine the format specs and warn of problems.

I suggest you cast the argument. I risk guessing and failing, but something like this

```
printf("m(%d,%d) is %f \n", x, y, *(float*)m_addroff);
```

Herer is a simple example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char car [4] = {0};
    char *cptr = car;
    printf ("Hello %f\n", *(float*)cptr);
    return 0;
}
```